# What is the safest way to pack syrup on a long-haul flight?

Tags: air-travel, fragile-luggage

I would like to bring some homemade syrup on a long-haul flight which requires a flight transfer. I am thinking of putting it into some empty 500ml plastic mineral water bottles. How to make sure it arrives intact at its destination?

Comment: You might want to add if you take it in hand luggage or not. If yes, quantities also matter.

Comment: What are you afraid of? Leaks? Confiscation?

Comment: @cdkMoose, thanks for the tip.  Close voted in favour of that link

Comment: @GayotFow given the ambiguity in this question, I am unsure whether it is a duplicate.  The syrup could be in a plastic bottle, for all we know.

Comment: @phoog, it has 4 votes now; if it's an unfair or bad closure, flag it and ping anybody in chat to reopen it.

Comment: You can just as easily pour the syrup into a zip lock or whatever, then freeze it, pack it along with silicone refreezable bags.  Unbreakable.

Comment: @GayotFow, thanks for the idea. Never heard of such a thing before. How long can the content stay frozen?

Answer (score 2):

Bubble wrap it and on top of the bubble wrap cello tap the bottle and keep them between the cloths somewhere middle of the bag.I usually follow this and it never leaks or break.Hope this helps you too.

Comment: I would add that if the bottle is plastic and unsealed it helps to squeeze out any air.